# get z standardized score within each group

Tags: r, lapply

Here is the data.

```
set.seed(23) data<-data.frame(ID=rep(1:12), group=rep(1:3,times=4), value=(rnorm(12,mean=0.5, sd=0.3)))

   ID group     value
1   1     1 0.4133934
2   2     2 0.6444651
3   3     3 0.1350871
4   4     1 0.5924411
5   5     2 0.3439465
6   6     3 0.3673059
7   7     1 0.3202062
8   8     2 0.8883733
9   9     3 0.7506174
10 10     1 0.3301955
11 11     2 0.7365258
12 12     3 0.1502212
```

I want to get z-standardized scores within each group. so I try

```
library(weights)
data_split<-split(data, data$group) #split the dataframe
stan<-lapply(data_split, function(x) stdz(x$value)) #compute z-scores within group
```

However, It looks wrong because I want to add a new variable following 'value'
How can I do that? Kindly provide some suggestions(sample code). Any help is greatly appreciated .

Answer (score 1):

Use this instead:

```
within(data, stan <- ave(value, group, FUN=stdz))
```

No need to call `split` nor `lapply`.

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I was looking for, and it is definitely the most elegant solution I found.

Answer (score 1):

One way using data.table package:

```
library(data.table)
library(weights)

set.seed(23)
data <- data.table(ID=rep(1:12), group=rep(1:3,times=4), value=(rnorm(12,mean=0.5, sd=0.3)))
setkey(data, ID)
dataNew <- data[, list(ID, stan = stdz(value)), by = 'group']
```

the result is:

```
    group ID       stan
 1:     1  1 -0.6159312
 2:     1  4  0.9538398
 3:     1  7 -1.0782747
 4:     1 10  0.7403661
 5:     2  2 -1.2683237
 6:     2  5  0.7839781
 7:     2  8  0.8163844
 8:     2 11 -0.3320388
 9:     3  3  0.6698418
10:     3  6  0.8674548
11:     3  9 -0.2131335
12:     3 12 -1.3241632
```

Comment: some reference: http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/vignettes/datatable-intro.pdf

Answer (score 1):

I tried Ferdinand.Kraft's solution but it didn't work for me. I think the `stdz` function isn't included in the basic R install. Moreover, the `within` part troubled me in a large dataset with many variables. I think the easiest way is:

```
data$value.s <- ave(data$value, data$group, FUN=scale)
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the new column while in your function, and have the function return the whole data frame.

```
stanL<-lapply(data_split, function(x) {
x$stan <- stdz(x$value)
x
})

stan <- do.call(rbind, stanL)
```